# Unable to call SessionFactory with a JSP file in a Spring MVC web app with JasperReports

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I am struggeling to retrieve my hibernate session with my jsp file. The session is to be used as a datasource for my report.

This is my JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*,net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*,net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRHibernateQueryExecuterFactory,org.hibernate.SessionFactory" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.io.*,java.util.HashMap" %>
<%

    String filename = "/WEB-INF/pages/tddd27.jrxml";
    String reporttype = "html";
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     String path = application.getRealPath("/");
     HashMap parameters = new HashMap();
     parameters.put(JRHibernateQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_HIBERNATE_SESSION, sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());

     JasperReport jasperReport =JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path + "/" + filename);

     JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters);
     System.out.println("Report Created...");

     OutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();

     JRExporter exporter = null;

     if( "pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
     {
          response.setContentType("application/pdf");
          exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
     }
     else if( "rtf".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
     {
          response.setContentType("application/rtf");
          response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"file.rtf\"");

          exporter = new JRRtfExporter();
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
     }
     else if( "html".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
     {
          exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
     }
     else if( "xls".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
     {
          response.setContentType("application/xls");
          response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"file.xls\"");

          exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
     }
     else if( "csv".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
     {
          response.setContentType("application/csv");
          response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"file.csv\"");

          exporter = new JRCsvExporter();
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
          exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
     }
     try 
     {
          exporter.exportReport();
     } 
     catch (JRException e) 
     {
          throw new ServletException(e);
     }
     finally
     {
          if (ouputStream != null)
          {
               try
               {
                    ouputStream.close();
               }
               catch (IOException ex)
               {
               }
          }
     }
%>
```

This is the error I get:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/pages/reportpage.jsp
The local variable sessionFactory may not have been initialized
11:     
12:      String path = application.getRealPath("/");
13:      HashMap parameters = new HashMap();
14:      parameters.put(JRHibernateQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_HIBERNATE_SESSION, sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
15:      
16:      JasperReport jasperReport =JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path + "/" + filename);
17:
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Is there a way to do this? Or is there an alternate way to connect my report to a hibernate datasource?

Comment: You're using Spring MVC. Why are you using JSPs to implement a controller? Use a Spring controller. JSPs should not contain Java code. That said, the message is extremely clear. You have not initialized the variable `sessionFactory`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I'll try implement it as a spring controller instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring MVC doing this stuff in your JSP is not the right place.
good option will be to use a suitable transaction manager, `@Transactional` for your service methods. try using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` in your DAO classes. It will return session associated with the current transaction.
If you want lazy loading of hibernate enteties on your JSP pages, you can configure OpenSessionInView filter in your web.xml.

for reference see: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it and get back to you in a couple of days.

Comment: Ok, so I've implemented hibernate according to this tutorial: [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/) I use  the getHibernateTemplate() instead of getCurrentSession(). I tried to change in my StockDaoImpl but that didn't work. I use XML mapping. Do I need to change the xml file?

Comment: If you are using hibernate 4, I suggest using getCurrentSession().